# Strategies to build real-time data grid using Oracle, Java & AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, json, oracle

This is my first stack-overflow post, so please ignore/forgive if I am not being specific enough.I'm sure I will learn the process gradually.

I have built a JSON to be displayed in angular data grid. This JSON comes from a complex query over materialized view.My thought to refresh the JSON as underlying data changes is as follows:
a) Register query for Oracle CQRN (Oracle Continuous Query Result Change Notification) at application startup
b) When the Underlying data changes, Oracle Database Change Listener in Java side gets invoked and Ire-query the data (with change) and push it to socket end-point. That way the JSON gets changed with latest data.

This works fine with simple query.

Issues are:
a) In my case the query is very complex and involves multiple materialized views with UNION ALL and complex JOINS. CQRN does not support materialized view registration for query result change.

b) The query I am registering at start-up, for query result change notification, is pretty static. It does not meet the requirement of various different parameterized queries behind the data-grid.

Can anyone suggest any other alternative for example cache the grid data in the middle-tire and and refresh cache with updated data whenever the underlying grid data changes. I should be notified when underlying grid data changes so I will re-query & send the updated data to socket end-point, which will refresh the grid.

I have to show the grid-data changes in real-time, so I have used Java WebSocket (JSR 356)

Technology stack:
UI: Javascaipt/AngularJS
Middle-tier: Java 1.7
Server: Jetty 9.2
Database: Oracle 11g R2
Build Platform: Maven 3.3

Suggestion for any other suitable approach also will be much appreciated.

Thanks & regards,
- Joy

Answer (score 1):

While not directly answering your question we just implemented a real time data grid involving multiple data sources and CQRN.  This built in is based on a table changing.  Our technique was:

- add on insert trigger (data feed was real time, no deletes, no updates) to the base tables
- call a stored procedure to manipulate the data.  You would use the logic in your materialized view.  The procedure inserts data into a destination table.  That has a trigger to call the CQRN.
- often with realtime you need to delete old data so everything stays fast